RG equation for elastic modulus of hexatic membrane
An elastic energy of the hexatic membrane can be written as
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}_h = \int dS (\delta_{ij} -l_i l_k) \nabla_i \phi \nabla_j \phi,
\end{equation}
where $l$ is the unit vector perpendicular to the membrane, $\phi$ is hexatic angle, i,j = {x,y,z}. Mebrane is parametrized by equation $z - u(x,y) =0$. Elastic energy is small correction to Helfrich energy:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F} = \int dS \frac{\kappa}{2} (\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2})^2,
\end{equation}
where $R_1$ and $R_2$ are local curvature radii of the membrane. Find an one-loop RG-equation for the elastic modulus B.
Helfrich energy can be rewriten through order parameter $u(x,y)$
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F} = \int dx dy \sqrt{1 + (\nabla u)^2} \frac{\kappa}{2} (\nabla_\alpha \frac{\nabla_\alpha u}{\sqrt{1 + (\nabla u)^2}})^2 \qquad \alpha = \{x,y\}
\end{equation}
Main part (from where $\langle u u\rangle$ arise) is $\int dx dy  \frac{\kappa}{2} (\nabla^2 u)^2$. Next i turn on calculating $\mathcal{F}_h$. Here i have problem, that in zero order if i neglect difference between flat and curved surface i have following freen energy functional.
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}^0_h = \int dxdy  \nabla_\alpha \phi(x,y,0) \nabla_\alpha \phi (x,y,0),
\end{equation}
I have problem, that $\phi(x,y,0)$ is still 3D, so it involves z component of wave length $k$. I couldn't though obtain zero order average $\langle\phi \phi \rangle$. Moreover it seems to me that RG correction comes from interaction part $\nabla_\alpha \phi(x,y,0) \nabla_\alpha u (\partial_z \phi |_{z=0})$. I don't know how to deal with $\partial_z \phi |_{z=0}$ term.
